# NodeJS MySQL says Syntax error, even though it isn't one

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am currently creating a little webserver, Servers of my Roblox game can send requests to, to store bans on my MySQL Server. I want my little Module to also have a function, that deletes the DataBase, and creates a new one. It just runs a query, which is read from a file.
Here's the part that reads from a file:

```js
var ResetQuery= "-- .";
fs.readFile("./SQL/Reset.sql","utf8",(error,data)=>{
    if(error){console.log("ERROR READING FILE: "+error.stack);return;}
    ResetQuery= data;
});
```

This is the resetall function:

```js
exports.resetAll = function(callback){
    runquery(ResetProjectBusQuery,[],()=>{
        callback();
    });
};
```

This is the ./SQL/Reset.sql script with the comments and spaces removed:

```sql
drop database BanData;
create database BanData; 
use BanData;
create table Bans(userId int not null primary key,banReason varchar(500) not null,bannedBy int not null,bannedOn int not null,banEnds int not null
);
```

When I execute that script in MySQL Workbench, or on PhpMyAdmin, everything works fine. When I use the resetAll function, in my module, I get this error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create database BanData;
>   use BanData;

Have you every experienced something similiar? What can I do?

Comment: Why `DROP` the database as well? Wouldn't it be better to simply `TRUNCATE` the table?

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Unfortunately, the issue is still here:

Comment: `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'truncate table bans' at line 7`